# In report card there is a star besides character name what does it means?

Tags: danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc

I was wondering that in report card there is a star beside a character. So what does it mean having star beside a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The star indicates that you have maximized your relationship with that character, so you no longer need to spend time with them, unless you want to.

Comment: What happens if I want to spend time with them

Comment: @swswsws. Nothing special happens. They'll act like they always do, only they won't tell you anything more about their lives, nor will they give you an additional skill or present. It's pretty pointless to spend any more time with them at that point.